# What verb form is correct in "The fuel of which is/are"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

Which of the sentence is correct?

> The fuel of which is petrol and gas
>
> The fuel of which are petrol and gas

Should there be is or are?

Comment: That is not the beginning of a sentence. You should provide a full sentence the explanation of which should be clear.

Answer (score 3):

As you've correctly noted, in English, it's the subject and the verb that need to be in agreement. The subject of your sentence is "the fuel", which is a singular noun, so the verb also needs to take a singular form. Hence:

> The fuel of which **is** petrol and gas.

You can read more about your specific issue at [Verbs Sandwiched
Between Singular and Plural Nouns](https://web.archive.org/web/20180121210521/https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/verbs-sandwiched-between-singular-and-plural-nouns).

Comment: (that said, it's a very awkward sentence - the "which" is dangling, the inverse structure makes the grammar more confusing than it should be, and finally "gas" should probably be described more precisely (as natural gas, propane, LPG...) to avoid confusion with AmE's "gas" meaning "petrol").